# Strange behaivour of Code on admin side

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, url, controllers, ajax

i am working on website where i import products with images from front side.Its works fine.Now i am trying to use same code on admin side but getting error on error.Like on first attempt i got 302 error so i append `?isAjax=true` to my url.Now i got another error of `{"error":true,"message":"Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."}`. Why the code differ for admin and front side.How to resolve the `invalid form key` ? .Thanks in advance

```
http://example.com/index.php/pmembers/adminhtml_import/importimages/key/1b15e0d33e0bd77554ff51ca3dfa8d5f/?isAjax=true&
```

My Form is like this

```
<form id="upload" method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("pmembers/adminhtml_import/importimages")?>?isAjax=true" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you built your import form.
If you built it using the magento `Form` classes this shouldn't happen.
If you have a simple phtml file for rendering the form you should add this inside your form tag

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I added my form code on question.

Comment: @Adda. Just as a I suspected. You are missing the form key hidden input. Add the line I mentioned in my answer inside your `<form>` tag.